# Pysat: PBEnc.atmost

Tags: python, encoding, pysat

[Hello, I can't understand the 2 examples of this library.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlnCt.png)

I tried to read but I can't understand why we obtain these clauses.
I can't understand the transformation from an inequality to these set of clauses.
I can't understand also the new introduction of values like 4, 5 and 6.